# php query sort the most or largest number of words

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any possible way or query for sorting the most word?

for example I have 300 rows and I have this in row 250

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit

and the row 250 got the most/largest amount of word in the column.

how can I sort that using `mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM wordlist")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method is to sort by the *length* of the column in characters, rather than the number of words:

```
select wl.*
from wordlist wl
order by char_length(wl.col) desc;
```

If you actually want words, then perhaps counting spaces is sufficient:

```
select wl.*
from wordlist wl
order by (length(wl.col) - length(replace(wl.col, ' ', ''))) desc;
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given` it gives me an error :/

Answer (score 1):

Gordon Linoff's answer is correct and I agree with it, however, I describe an alternative solution. You could store the number of words into the `wordlist` `table` in a new `column`. And you could write an `insert` and `update` [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) which would do the calculations shown in Gordon Linoff's answer and store the result into the affected record's corresponding field. In that case number of words would be calculated once per record change, or even on specific `column` change on the record and could read the stored value as many times you like.

Comment: wow nice algorithm. I didn't think about that. This is useful. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MarverickM., I was happy to help you.